# Add nested input and label to a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, appendchild

I am trying to use JavaScript to add a div, within that an input and label, inside a div in the body.  The color variable inside the JavaScript will eventually live somewhere else in the file, but I added it here so that it makes sense where the codes and labels are coming from.  So basically the sudo code looks like this...

```
div (that's already in the body)
   div (from JS)
      input (from JS)
      label (from JS)
   </div>
```

Here is what I have so far [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/douglas_fordham/5abLxv2z/), and the code is also shown below

### HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
  </head>
  <body onload="buildTheColors()">
  <form id="colorChoose">
  <div class="firstBox">
  <br>
    <div id="mainContainer">
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

### JavaScript

```
var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();

var colors = [ 
['Dark Grey', 'dark_grey', '#4d4d4d'],
['Medium Grey', 'medium_grey', '#717171'],
['Medium Dark Grey', 'medium_dark_grey', '#9a9a9a'],
['Default Grey','light_grey','#c1c1c1'],
['47th Shade of Grey', 'lighter_grey', '#e0e0e0'],

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {

  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var newInput = document.createElement('input');
  var newLabel = document.createElement('LABEL');

    newDiv.class = 'radio-item';

    newInput.type = "radio";
    newInput.id = 'I'+colors[i][1];
    newInput.name = "colorsman";
    newInput.value = colors[i][1];


    newLabel.style.background = colors[i][2];

    newDiv.appendChild(newInput);
    newDiv.appendChild(newLabel);

    toAdd.appendChild(newDiv);

   }
document.getElementById('mainContainer').appendChild(toAdd);
```

### CSS

```
.radio-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.radio-item input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.radio-item label {
  color: #666;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.radio-item label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  border: 2px solid #004c97;
  background-color: transparent;}

.radio-item input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
  border-radius: 11px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 12px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: #004c97;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you Go!!

Updated my answer

```js
var toAdd = document.createElement("div");

    var colors = [ 
    ['Dark Grey', 'dark_grey', '#4d4d4d'],
    ['Medium Grey', 'medium_grey', '#717171'],
    ['Medium Dark Grey', 'medium_dark_grey', '#9a9a9a'],
    ['Default Grey','light_grey','#c1c1c1'],
    ['47th Shade of Grey', 'lighter_grey', '#e0e0e0']]

    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
      var newInput = document.createElement('input');
      var newLabel = document.createElement('LABEL');

        newDiv.className = 'radio-item';

        newInput.type = "radio";
        newInput.id = 'I'+colors[i][1];
        newInput.name = "colorsman";
        newInput.value = colors[i][1];


        newLabel.style.color = colors[i][2];
        newLabel.innerText=colors[i][0];
        newLabel.setAttribute("for",'I'+colors[i][1]);

        newDiv.appendChild(newInput);
        newDiv.appendChild(newLabel);

        toAdd.appendChild(newDiv);

       }
    document.getElementById('mainContainer').appendChild(toAdd);
```

```css
.radio-item {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0 6px;
      margin: 10px 0 0;
    }

    .radio-item input[type='radio'] {
      display: none;
    }

    .radio-item label {
      color: #666;
      font-weight: normal;
    }

    .radio-item label:before {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      top: 5px;
      margin: 0 5px 0 0;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      border-radius: 11px;
      border: 2px solid #004c97;
      background-color: transparent;}

    .radio-item input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
      border-radius: 11px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 11px;
      left: 12px;
      content: " ";
      display: block;
      background: #004c97;
    }
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form id="colorChoose">
      <div class="firstBox">
      <br>
        <div id="mainContainer">
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: AWESOME!!!!!!!!!! Okay, so it creates a square background with the colors behind the circle. Any idea how to get them to be circles?

Comment: Okay, so now it displays the name of the color, but doesn't put the background in.  Hmmm.....I'm trying to get the label round so that it shows up in the circle where the radio button is hidden. Thoughts?

Comment: Snap, nvm. I got it with changing the CSS.  I've updated the JSFiddle above

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask a question, however your fiddle contains errors:

- there's no `buildTheColors()` function
- your `var colors = [`  is missing the end `];`

If you fix that, you'll see radio-inputs appearing.